# How to get checked value from radio button in human task form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jbpm, kie

Following is my HTML source code. If I select any of the radio buttons in human task form,the output value always returns the value of the last radio button. (here :`NotClean`)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Document varification</h2>
        <hr>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Outcome" value="Done">Done<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Outcome" value="NotClean">NotClean<br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `$('[name="Outcome"]:checked').val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>sample Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('button').click(function () {
                var Outcome;

                Outcome = $('input[name="Outcome"]:checked').val();


                if (Outcome == "Done") {
                    alert('condition1')
                }
                else if (Outcome == "NotClean") {

                    alert('condition2')
                    }

            })

        });


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button >check Condition</button>
       <input type="radio" name="Outcome" value="Done" >Done<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Outcome" value="NotClean">NotClean<br/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Still the output value always returns the value of the last radio button.

Comment: only one radio button can select at a time . right??

Comment: Yes Shriya. If i select Done radio then the output returning NotClean

Comment: no. that will never happen

Comment: What i am trying to achieve here is. If i select Done radio then the value string "Done" should assign to variable Outcome. So that i can put condition using Outcome variable.                                                       If i select Done radio ------   Outcome="Done"                                                                       If i select NotClean radio --------  Outcome="NotClean"

Comment: code edited plz check :)